# How to find subsequences?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I'm given a random sequence of numbers of random length, consisting of 0's, 1's, 2's:

```
201102220221
```

I'm also given a number: either 1 or 2. **I can only loop through the sequence once**, and I need to identify all the subsequences of the number I'm given, run that value through another function and add the value to a sum (initialized to 0).

Any 0's can be replaced with a 1 or a 2. Subsequences can therefore be "expanded", by replacing 0's beside it with the number. If a subsequence cannot be expanded to a minimum length of more than 4, I need to discard it.

For example, say I'm given the sequence:

```
11011002102
```

and the number 1. I identify the subsequence of length 2 at the beginning (See first element). It can be expanded to a subsequence of length 7, by replacing the first 0, third and fourth zero with 1's. Therefore I run its current length through a function and add it to the sum.

```
sum += function(2);
```

I then identify the next subsequence of 1's (See fourth element). It's currently of size 2 and can be expanded to a maximum size of 7, by replacing the zeros around it. So I pass its length to a function and add it to the sum.

```
sum += function (2);
```

I finally identify the last subsequence of 1's (See sixth element). It currently has a length of 1 and can be expanded to a maximum size of 2, by replacing the zero beside it with a 1, which is less than 4, so I discard it.

Could someone help me write a function that does what was described above by **only looping through the sequence once**. **Please do not give me real code, just ideas, suggestions or pseudocode**.

I don't have any work to share, I'm completely lost. I also know no algorithms, so please don't start talking about things like dynamic programming or linear programming, but instead explain possible ways to approach the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't use the word _sequence_ to mean both the randomly generated numbers, and consecutive, same numbers. Kind of confusing.

Comment: @Laksa How about "subsequences"?

Comment: classic [dp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) problem. Start with what you know and expand by keeping track of what you previously got. Hint: You are only concerned about the number you are looking for and any zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the requirement that you can only loop through the sequence once, you know the basic structure of the code.

Given the parameters for discarding a subsequence (expanded length of 4 or more) and for processing a subsequence (unexpanded sequence length), you know what data you need to track along the way. Work out how to best store this data according to your environment and language conventions.

At each iteration of the loop, consider the current character of the input series and how it affects the data stored.

I've tried to clarify the question here without just handing you the solution. Feel free to ask more questions.

Edit:

Consider how you would break the problem down step by step. Here are the iterations of your for loop:

```
1----------
```

Okay, we're looking for `1`s and we've found one straight up.

```
-1---------
```

Cool, another `1`, now our subsequence length has increased to 2

```
--0--------
```

Right, so as this is not a `1`, the length of this subsequence is now known to be 2 - it doesn't increase any more, but as this is a `0`, it might still qualify if it can expand to at least 4. The expanded subsequence length is now `3`.

```
---1-------
```

The expanded subsequence length is now `4`! This means we can add the last sequence length to the total sum after passing it through `function`. This is also the start of another subsequence - so subsequence length is now reset to `1`, but expanded subsequence length is still valid at `4`. That means that this subsequence is already long enough not to be rejected, but we haven't finished counting it's length at this stage.

```
----1------
```

`subsequence length` = `2`, and `expanded subsequence length` = `5`

```
-----0-----
```

This marks the end of the 2nd subsequence, process it as before. Etc

```
------0----
-------2--- <- expanded subsequence length gets reset here
--------1-- <- start of another subsequence
---------0- <- expanded length is 2
----------2 <- expanded length is not long enough for this to qualify, discard it
```

So, fairly straight forward. There are two factors we need to keep track of: `subsequence length` and `expanded subsequence length`.

Once you've got that working, think about what happens for this input sequence "1010101".

Comment: Thanks! I still don't know how to approach the problem after adding a for loop to loop through the sequence. Could you please add in a few more hints for a the solution? I literally have no experience with algorithms, I only started programming 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Yup, I kept track of the current sequence and the last two sequences. When I reached a fourth sequence or a '2', I calculated the three sequences, and reset everything. It works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Forget the computer for a bit; think of it as a faster version of using pencil and paper.

Try to imagine how you would solve this problem as you traverse each element of the sequence; what you might want to write down and/or edit on your piece of paper at each iteration (each element you reach in the sequence).

For example:

```
Sequence = 11011002102
Index 0:
    Value is 1
    Current is 1, Previous was null
    Tracking a subsequence of 1's starting at 0 => [1,0] = 1
Index 1:
    Value is 1
    Current is 1, Previous was 1
    Current == Previous so the subsequence length is increased by 1 => [1,0] = 2
...
```